# Network port mounting bracket/box

Tags: ethernet, infrastructure

Does anyone known of a source for open back, low voltage, [old work, electrical boxes](http://www.hammerzone.com/archives/elect/remodel1/lighting/track2ft/oldworkbox.htm) that are intended to be installed through the Sheetrock and mount to [studs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall_stud)?

I've found boxes for old construction like [this](http://www.parts-express.com/pe/showdetl.cfm?Partnumber=261-431) that mount on the Sheetrock and for new construction like [this](http://www.parts-express.com/pe/showdetl.cfm?Partnumber=261-433) and [this](http://www.hometech.com/hts/products/wiring/wallboxes/low_voltage/cn-sc200a.html) that mount to the studs.

What I have is an existing building where I need to install Ethernet cable inside the walls without ripping out all the Sheetrock. I'm not to thrilled with the Sheetrock mounted boxes and know that with some effort a box can be mounted on the studs (I've seen it done).

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about your application and the problem you need solved? Also what "old work" means? I've wired many offices/homes with Ethernet, so may know what you are talking about in different terms.

Comment: @AdamB: "Old work" means "retrofit".

Comment: @AdamB: Or remodel.

Comment: Ummm, I'm pretty sure old work box effectively means mount to sheetrock; new work effectively means mount to stud... Why can't you use new work boxes? And what's wrong with mounting the sheetrock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This type](https://web.archive.org/web/20130517195357/http://www.smarthome.com/2552/1-Gang-Old-Work-Low-Voltage-Box-Bracket-SC100RR-SC100R/p.aspx) is a little deeper than the example that you gave and might accommodate having a couple of holes drilled in one side and then driving screws through them into a stud.

[image: Low voltage old-work box]
<sub>(source: [smarthome.com](https://cache1.smarthome.com/images/2552.jpg))</sub>

Comment: I was keeping that kind of solution in mind as a back up. (+1) But once I'm modding stuff, I can get a standard 120V box and run it thorough a table saw for about $0.75 a piece.